# Having trouble getting variable to pass to jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a save feature on my website so that the user can save an item. On the first click it updates and saves fine because it went through the PHP file, but what I am having trouble with is getting the ajax to update the link when clicked the second time since the link is created in the jquery code for updating it with AJAX. (passing the proper ID's is the problem) It should update the heart to red or green and add or remove the word 'Save'. I need to get the proper id updated on the second, third, etc. click.
Here is the jquery code:
I have 2 functions. saveLink and deleteLink.

This is my javascript file:

```
$(document).on("click", '.del-button', function () {
var savId = $(this).attr('data-sav-id');
deleteLink(savId);
});

$(document).on("click", '.sav-button', function () {
    var delId = $(this).attr('data-del-id');
    saveLink(delId);
});

function saveLink( saveID ){

var id = saveID;

$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "saveLink.php",
    dataType: "json",
    data:  { 

        'id' : id,

    },

    success: function(returnID){
        var returnID = $.trim(returnID);
        if(returnID){           

            $('#showSaved' + id).html('<span id="removeSaved('+ id +');"><a href="javascript:void();" class="del-button pull-right"' + 'data-sav-id='+ returnID +'"><i class="fa fa-heart" style="color:#d52917;"></i></a></span>');    

        }
    }
});
}

function deleteLink( deleteID ){

var deletedID = deleteID;

$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "deleteLink.php",
    dataType: "json",
    data:  { 

        'deletedID' : deletedID,

    },

    success: function(deleteIDFunc){
        var deleteIDFunc = $.trim(deleteIDFunc);
        if(deleteIDFunc){   

            $('#removeSaved' + deletedID).html('<span id="showSaved('+ deletedID +');"><a href="javascript:void();" class="sav-button pull-"' + 'data-del-id='+ deleteIDFunc + '">Save <i class="fa fa-heart"></i></a></span>');

        }
        else {
            alert('Your saved post was not removed. Please try again');
        }
    }
});
}
```

Here is the PHP code that handles the initial click:

```
$query = "SELECT        
        count(replies.reply_topic) as replyCount,
        topics.topic_id,
        topics.topic_subject,
        topics.topic_date,
        topics.topic_cat,
        topics.topic_creator,
        topics.topic_likes,
        users.user_id,
        users.username,
        profile.profile_id,
        profile.profile_pictureMain,
        profile.profile_users,
        savelink.saveLink_id,
        savelink.saveUser_id,
        savelink.link_id
        FROM
            topics
        LEFT JOIN
            users
        ON
            topics.topic_creator = users.user_id
        LEFT JOIN
            replies
        ON
            replies.reply_topic = topics.topic_id
        LEFT JOIN
            profile
        ON
            profile.profile_users = users.user_id
        LEFT JOIN
            savelink
        ON
            savelink.link_id = topics.topic_id
        GROUP BY
            topics.topic_id
        ORDER BY
            topics.topic_date DESC 
        LIMIT ?, ?
        ";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindParam(1, $start, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $limit, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
$returnAmt = $stmt->fetchAll();
if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
$returnValues = "";
foreach($returnAmt as $row){
    $returnValues .=
if(isset($_SESSION['user_session']) && $row['saveUser_id'] == $_SESSION['user_session']){
        $returnValues .= '<span id="removeSaved'.$row['saveLink_id'].'"><a href="javascript:void();" class="del-button pull-right" data-sav-id="'.$row['saveLink_id'].'"><i class="fa fa-heart" style="color:#d52917;"></i></a></span>';
    }
    else if(isset($_SESSION['user_session'])){
        $returnValues .= '<span id="showSaved'.$row['topic_id'].'"><a href="javascript:void();" class="sav-button pull-right" data-del-id="'.$row['topic_id'].'">Save <i class="fa fa-heart"></i></a></span>';
    }
    else{
        $returnValues .= '<a href="javascript:void();" class="pull-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal" >Save <i class="fa fa-heart"></i></a>';
    }

    $returnValues .= '</div></div></span></div>
}
echo $returnValues;
```

Here is the html code for displaying the results:

```
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="Top">

    <div id="rowDisplayResults">

        <!--Display results here-->

    </div>

</div>
```

This is what I would like the save feature to look like. A red heart when saved and green when not.

[image]

Should I be adding another variable to the save and delete link functions to pass the proper ID's after the second click?
Any help would be much appreciated. thanks.

Comment: Since your links are created during run-time using jQuery use please use document.on

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like this. Also change the html for this logic

```js
 $(document).on("click", '.del-button', function () {
            var savId = $(this).attr('data-sav-id');
            deleteLink(savId);
        });

        $(document).on("click", '.sav-button', function () {
            var delId = $(this).attr('data-del-id');
            saveLink(delId);
        });

        function saveLink( saveID ){
            var id = saveID;
            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "saveLink.php",
                dataType: "json",
                data:  { 
                    'id' : id,
                },
                success: function(returnID){
                    var returnID = $.trim(returnID);
                    if(returnID){           

                        $('#showSaved' + id).html('<span id="removeSaved('+ id +');"><a href="javascript:void();" class="del-button pull-right"'+
                            ' data-sav-id=' + returnID + '"><i class="fa fa-heart" style="color:#d52917;"></i></a></span>');
                        //onclick="deleteLink('+ returnID +');
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        function deleteLink(deleteID) {
            var deletedID = deleteID;
            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "deleteLink.php",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    'deletedID': deletedID,
                },
                success: function (deleteIDFunc) {
                    var deleteIDFunc = $.trim(deleteIDFunc);
                    if (deleteIDFunc) {
                        $('#removeSaved' + deletedID).html('<span id="showSaved(' + deletedID + ');"><a href="javascript:void();" '+
                            'class="pull-right sav-button" data-del-id=' + deleteIDFunc + '">Save <i class="fa fa-heart"></i></a></span>');
                    }
                        //onclick="saveLink(' + deleteIDFunc + ');
                    else {
                        alert('Your saved post was not removed. Please try again');
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Hi @Ratheesh, thanks for the reply, I tried the changes that you offered but it still does the same thing. It only updates the icon on the first click but have to refresh page for it to update the next time.

Comment: Sorry, if you could share the rendered html for that rowDisplayResults div, it is more helpful

Comment: I updated the code with a picture of what I am looking to accomplish.

Comment: removeSaved('+ id +'); 
showSaved('+ deletedID +');

are assigned to id? I think it is wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186695/discussion-between-ratheesh-and-stuckfornow).